# How to disable hyperlink security notice in OneNote 2016?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-onenote-2016

Every time I open a link to a local file in OneNote 2016, I get this annoying popup:

[image]

There [used to be a setting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-security-alerts-about-links-and-files-from-suspicious-websites-a1ac6ae9-5c4a-4eb3-b3f8-143336039bbe) in the Trust Center to disable this, but it no longer exists in Office 2016

[image]

I also tried adding a [DisableHyperlinkWarning](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fc545f8-dd71-4f79-9847-dc786eb02217/onenote-2016-disable-hyperlink-warning?forum=Office2016ITPro) regedit key, but that did not work. The asker of the linked question was not able to disable the warning with this approach either, so I assume this was removed in Office 2016 as well.

Is there any way for me to disable this security notice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had success following the registry key steps from this guide: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365legacy-mso_oapps/office-365onenote-security-notice-settings/a4f9120a-3c39-44fc-9c1f-b8f76fd79b00?auth=1

From the post:

1. In the Registry Editor, locate the following subkey:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common
   ```
2. On the menu bar, click *Edit* → *New* → *Key* and type `Security` and press Enter.
3. Right click Security, then click *New* → *DWORD (32-bit) Value* and type `DisableHyperlinkWarning` and press Enter.
4. Double click the above value, select *Decimal* and change the Value data to `1`, then click OK.

**The `DisableHyperlinkWarning` key value was added, but a comment below pointed out the trailing space accidentally being added to the end of the value name.**

After I removed the space the popup stopped for me.